# How do I get the complexity of bilinear/nearest neighbour interpolation algorithm? (calculate the big O)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, nearest-neighbor, image-scaling, bilinear-interpolation

I want to calculate the big O of the following algorithms for resizing binary images:

*Bilinear interpolation:*

```
double scale_x = (double)new_height/(height-1);
        double scale_y = (double)new_width/(width-1);

        for (int i = 0; i < new_height; i++)
        {
            int ii = i / scale_x;
            for (int j = 0; j < new_width; j++)
            {
                int jj = j / scale_y;
                double v00 = matrix[ii][jj], v01 = matrix[ii][jj + 1],
                        v10 = matrix[ii + 1][jj], v11 = matrix[ii + 1][jj + 1];
                double fi = i / scale_x - ii, fj = j / scale_y - jj;
                double temp = (1 - fi) * ((1 - fj) * v00 + fj * v01) +
                    fi * ((1 - fj) * v10 +  fj * v11);
                if (temp >= 0.5)
                    result[i][j] = 1;
                else
                    result[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
```

*Nearest neighbour interpolation*

```
double scale_x = (double)height/new_height;
    double scale_y = (double)width/new_width;

    for (int i = 0; i < new_height; i++)
    {
        int srcx = floor(i * scale_x);
        for (int j = 0; j < new_width; j++)
        {
            int srcy = floor(j * scale_y);
            result[i][j] = matrix[srcx][srcy];
        }
    }
```

I assumed that the complexity of both of them is the loop dimensions, i.e O(new_height*new_width). However, the bilinear interpolation surely works much slower than the nearest neighbour. Could you please explain how to correctly compute complexity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both running in `Theta(new_height*new_width)` time because except for the loop iterations all operations are constant time.

This doesn't in any way imply that the two programs will execute equally fast. It merely means that if you increase `new_height` and/or `new_width` to infinity, the ratio of execution time between the two programs will neither go to infinity nor to zero.

(This is making the assumption that the integer types are unbounded and that all arithmetic operations are constant time operations independent of the length of the operands. Otherwise there will be another relevant factor accounting for the cost of the arithmetic.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Helped me understand the difference between the running time and the program execution time